# Rails gives me an unique error: RuntimeError: Session collision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, memcached

I get this error:
**RuntimeError: Session collision on '"6a17879bbd78f0ee4dbc823e3cd50682"'**

The app is configured using: **unicorn, memcached.**

session_store.rb is:

**Bulevard::Application.config.session_store :mem_cache_store, :key => '_bulevard_session', :expire_after => 10.minutes**

production.rb is:

**config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store**

Here is the full airbrake trace:

```
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/memcache.rb:54:in `block in get_session'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/memcache.rb:80:in `with_lock'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/memcache.rb:50:in `get_session'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:236:in `load_session'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:47:in `block in load_session'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:55:in `stale_session_check!'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:47:in `load_session'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:122:in `load!'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:118:in `load_for_write!'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:71:in `[]='
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:100:in `form_authenticity_token'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:53:in `form_authenticity_token'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb:23:in `csrf_meta_tags'
app/views/shared/_head.html.erb:30:in `_app_views_shared__head_html_erb___2281751522169299485_22292500'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:171:in `block in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:169:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:256:in `render_partial'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:227:in `block in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:219:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/layouts/pictures.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_pictures_html_erb___1703071847365294431_22026920'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:171:in `block in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:169:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_with_layout'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:250:in `_render_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:43:in `render_to_body'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/opt/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.10/lib/thinking_sphinx/action_controller.rb:12:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__108937060683959279__process_action__92800621948533106__callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `optimized_each'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/omniauth-1.0.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:168:in `call!'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/omniauth-1.0.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:148:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/omniauth-1.0.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:34:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
```